# How to get indirect access on a file through script in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, permissions, sudo

I have one file text1, on this only one user(user1) has read,write,execute permissions, rest of the world(user2) has read and execute permissions. 
I thought of having one script which changes the contents of the file text1 as below which will be executed by user2

sed -i '/s/eg1/eg0/' text1

I want to modify the above script to change the contents of text1 with out directly giving write access to user2. I mean to say user2 shouldn't able to directly write to text1 but when he executes the script the contents of text1 should be modified as it is not possible to give direct write access on text1

Comment: without receiving write access context (sudo, ...) there is NO write access by definition. If this could be done, there is no interest of write access feature.

Comment: This can be solved through `sudo`.  With `sudo`, you can give user2 permission to run that command and only that command with the permissions of user1.

Comment: Hi John1024 if you don't mind can you please give me that command. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` can allow `user2` to execute that command as `user1`.  To do that, run `sudo visudo`.  This will open an editor. Add the following line to the bottom of that file

```
user2 ALL=(user1)  NOPASSWD: /bin/sed -i s/eg1/eg0/ text1
```

Save the file and close the editor.  After this is done, `user2` can execute the command as follows:

```
sudo -u user1 sed -i 's/eg1/eg0/' text1
```

#### Notes

- `visudo` will open a system-dependent default editor.  That editor is often from the `vi` family.  If so, press `G` to get to the bottom of the file, `i` to enter insert mode, type or paste in the line, then press `Escape` to leave insert mode, then type `:x` to save and exit.
- Note that the line entered in the `sudo` file should not include the quotes that may be used on the command line.